# I need explanation of how JS deals with sorting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

assume there is array

> let arr = [10, 12, 3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 9, 4];

Trying this

> arr.sort((a, b) => a > b);
>
> // Results: [1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12]

But, using this

> arr.sort((a, b) => a - b) ;
>
> // Results: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12]

```js
let arr = [10, 12, 3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 9, 4];

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a > b));

let arr1 = [10, 12, 3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 9, 4];

console.log(arr1.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Comment: Default sort comparator assumes *strings*, not numbers.

Comment: I get the same (correct) result for both arrays in your snippet. What JS engine are you running this in?

Comment: because `a > b` is not enough as result of comparator, it returns 1 if a > b, but 0 in all other cases, while it should return -1 if a < b

Comment: @Pointy Incorrect. If for some reason it converted them to strings, then the result would be `[1, 10, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9]`

Comment: @OrangeDog Note first 4 numbers [1, 4, 3, 2, ]

Comment: @KhogaEslam yes I know. I'm saying that when I run it I don't get that.

Comment: Interesting post about this topic: https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort

Comment: @OrangeDog [you might want to read up on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Pointy as might you. That's if no compare function is provided, and as I said the result would be `[1, 10, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9]`

Comment: Right OK, I guess we're saying the same thing. With no compare function, the default is to interpret the array contents as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good reading to understand how [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works

To quote something relevant to your question:

> If compareFunction(a, b)
>   is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with
>   respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>   elements.
>
> Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>   behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating
>   back to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) is
>   greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a, i.e. b comes first.

And this:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a > b);
```

returns `true` or `false` which evaluates to 1 or 0, never -1

So, with this "incomplete" function, the result depends on the sorting algorithm used by the engine where your code is being executed

- **rhino.js**: 10,12,3,2,5,1,9,7,8,9,4
- **SpiderMonkey**: 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,9,10,12
- **v8**: 1,4,3,2,5,7,8,9,9,10,12